# how to have list of all tables in a database with dbo schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i do this with filter table in object explorer but i want do this with query 
and when i execute the query,returns all tables with dbo schema and their fields.

Comment: Look at the `information_schema` views

Comment: Try, `Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` as @HoneyBadger suggests.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'```

Comment: What if you have other `schemas` besides `dbo`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA maybe that is why he is asking this, because he might have more than one schema and he only wants to see tables from dbo. Im just guessing here off course

Comment: @GuidoG agreed, but just want to make sure they are aware. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returns from `sys.tables` , use `schema_id` to filter

```
SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS TableName
FROM sys.tables where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo'
```

To Include Views in Schema

```
SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS TableName
FROM sys.tables where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo'

UNION 

SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS TableName
FROM sys.views where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo'
```

Comment: you could do a union all on table 'sys.views' if you also want to see the views in the result

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get this information?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_id = 1
--SchemaId 1 is for 'dbo' schema
```

If you want columns as well, then try this.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

Comment: Did you try your first answer? It does not give the schema. It gives a column `schema_id` with a value of `1`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, Schema_Id = 1 gives the .dbo schema

Comment: Agreed, but it does not show the `.dbo` schema in the results.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct :) But user wants the list of tables which fall under dbo schema

Comment: Generally, you should not write code that makes assumptions about IDs and their meaning. @Bhouse has a much better suggestion

Comment: Yes. Not sure if they want to show it though, but +1 for your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get All the Table, Schema, Columns and data Type in database use below query.

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```